# rails4でslim内でsassを利用した際に外部sass変数をimportするには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, slim-lang

index.html.slim

```
h1 welcome to my page

sass:
  @import '/stylesheets/define.sass'
  h1
    color: $theme-color
```

define.sass

```
$theme_color: #FF0000
```

上記のindex.html.slimようなslim内部に直接sassを記述してスタイルを適応したい場合。
独立したdefine.sassファイルに定義したsass変数をslim内sassでインポートして利用したいのですが
以下の様なエラーが表示されdefine.sassをインポートすることが出来ません。

```
File to import not found or unreadable: /stylesheets/define.sass.
```

slim内sassでdefine.sassで定義した変数をインポートするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 「@import 'stylesheeshts/define.sass'」とするとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: File to import not found or unreadable: stylesheets/define.sass.というようなエラーが表示されました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それでは index.html.slim ファイルと define.saas ファイルの絶対パスを教えていただけますか？

Comment: 素早いご対応感謝いたします。解決しましたのでご連絡差し上げます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問者本人です。

```
@import 'app/assets/stylesheets/define.sass'
```

で解決しました。